# Custom Tkinter Script Closes Immediately Upon .exe. What is the issue?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that uses customtkinter as the gui that when executed, a gui pops up on my screen, allows me to record my working time and associated projects for that day, then saves it to a folder on my computer. The script works perfectly in Pycharm, but when I try and run it through Task Scheduler or execute the project myself, it opens then closes immediately without any user imput. I added an input function at the end to try and fix this and it did not help, unfortunately. Here is the current script:

```
import os
import time
import customtkinter as ctk
import glob

# Set appearance mode and default color theme
ctk.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

# Create CTk window
app = ctk.CTk()
app.title("Today's Projects & Hours Worked")

# Define the file path where you want to save the data
file_directory = r"C:\Users\username\OneDrive - Company Name\Desktop\Department\Folder name"


# Function to save hours and projects to file
def save_to_file(projects, hours):
    # Get today's date
    today_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    # Define the file path including the directory
    file_path = os.path.join(file_directory, f"work_log_{today_date}.txt")

    # Write the data to the file
    with open(file_path, "a") as file:
        # Write header
        file.write(f"{'Project':<30}{'Hours Worked':<15}\n")
        file.write("=" * 45 + "\n")

        # Write data
        total_hours = sum(float(hour) for hour in hours)
        for project, hour in zip(projects, hours):
            file.write(f"{project:<30}{hour:<15}\n")

        # Write sum of hours worked
        file.write("=" * 45 + "\n")
        file.write(f"{'Total Hours':<30}{total_hours:<15}\n")

    print("Hours and projects saved successfully.")


# Function to handle button click and save data
def save_data(entries):
    projects = []
    hours = []
    for entry in entries:
        project = entry[0].get()
        hour = entry[1].get()
        if project:  # Ensure project name is not empty
            projects.append(project)
        if hour:
            try:
                hour_float = float(hour)
                if hour_float > 0:  # Check if hour is positive numeric
                    hours.append(hour)
                else:
                    print(f"Invalid hours entered for project '{project}'. Please enter a positive numerical value.")
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Invalid hours entered for project '{project}'. Please enter a valid numerical value.")
        else:
            print(f"No hours entered for project '{project}'. Please enter hours.")

    if projects and hours:
        save_to_file(projects, hours)
        app.quit()


# Function to update the total hours and progress bar
def update_total_and_progress(entries, total_label, progress_bar):
    total_hours = 0
    for entry in entries:
        hour = entry[1].get()
        if hour and is_numeric(hour) and float(hour) > 0:  # Check if hour is positive numeric
            total_hours += float(hour)
    total_label.configure(text=f"Total Hours: {total_hours}")

    # Update progress bar
    progress_percentage = min(total_hours / 8, 1.0)  # Ensure the progress is capped at 100%
    progress_bar.set(progress_percentage)

    # Change progress bar color if total hours exceed 8 hours
    if total_hours > 8:
        progress_bar.configure(progress_color="red")
    else:
        progress_bar.configure(progress_color=("lightgreen", "green"))  # Set back to default green color


# Helper function to check if a string is numeric
def is_numeric(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


# Function to display the content from the last saved text file
def display_previous_entry():
    # Find all text files in the directory
    text_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_directory, "*.txt"))
    if text_files:
        # Get the path of the last modified text file
        latest_file = max(text_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        # Read the content of the file
        with open(latest_file, "r") as file:
            content = file.read()

            # Create a custom dialog window
            previous_entry_dialog = ctk.CTk()
            previous_entry_dialog.title("Previous Data Entry")

            # Display the content in a label
            content_label = ctk.CTkLabel(previous_entry_dialog, text=content)
            content_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

            # Add a button to close the dialog window
            close_button = ctk.CTkButton(previous_entry_dialog, text="Close", command=previous_entry_dialog.destroy)
            close_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

            # Run the custom dialog window
            previous_entry_dialog.mainloop()
    else:
        ctk.messagebox.showinfo("Previous Data Entry", "No previous data entry found.")


# Create and place entry widgets for projects and hours
entries = []

for i in range(10):  # Adjust the range for the number of projects you want to track
    project_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text=f"Project {i + 1}:")
    project_label.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    project_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(app)
    project_entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    hour_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="Hours:")
    hour_label.grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    hour_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(app)
    hour_entry.grid(row=i, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

    entries.append((project_entry, hour_entry))

# Create and place total hours label
total_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text="Total Hours: 0")
total_label.grid(row=len(entries), column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=10)

# Create and place progress bar
progress_bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(app, orientation="horizontal")
progress_bar.grid(row=len(entries), column=5, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=10)

# Create and place save button
save_button = ctk.CTkButton(app, text="Save", command=lambda: save_data(entries))
save_button.grid(row=len(entries) + 1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

# Create and place "Previous Data Entry" button
previous_entry_button = ctk.CTkButton(app, text="Previous Data Entry", command=display_previous_entry)
previous_entry_button.grid(row=len(entries) + 1, column=3, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

# Bind the entry widgets to update the total hours and progress bar when the text changes
for entry in entries:
    entry[1].bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event, entry_widgets=entries, total_label=total_label,
                                         progress_bar=progress_bar: update_total_and_progress(entry_widgets,
                                                                                              total_label,
                                                                                              progress_bar))

# Run the customtkinter event loop
app.mainloop()

# Add input function to prevent the console from closing immediately
input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

I tried manually executing the file and adding an input function to the end of the script

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past, and maybe it could be still valid for you, by encapsulate the entire GUI code inside a function and call that function when the script is executed directly. This way, the script won’t terminate until the GUI window is closed.

```
import os
import time
import customtkinter as ctk
import glob

# Set appearance mode and default color theme
ctk.set_appearance_mode(“System”)  # Modes: system (default), light, dark
ctk.set_default_color_theme(“blue”)  # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green

# Create CTk window
app = ctk.CTk()
app.title(“Today’s Projects & Hours Worked”)

# Define the file path where you want to save the data
file_directory = r”C:\Users\username\OneDrive - Company Name\Desktop\Department\Folder name”


# Function to save hours and projects to file
def save_to_file(projects, hours):
    # Get today’s date
    today_date = time.strftime(“%Y-%m-%d”)

    # Define the file path including the directory
    file_path = os.path.join(file_directory, f”work_log_{today_date}.txt”)

    # Write the data to the file
    with open(file_path, “a”) as file:
        # Write header
        file.write(f”{‘Project’:<30}{‘Hours Worked’:<15}\n”)
        file.write(“=” * 45 + “\n”)

        # Write data
        total_hours = sum(float(hour) for hour in hours)
        for project, hour in zip(projects, hours):
            file.write(f”{project:<30}{hour:<15}\n”)

        # Write sum of hours worked
        file.write(“=” * 45 + “\n”)
        file.write(f”{‘Total Hours’:<30}{total_hours:<15}\n”)

    print(“Hours and projects saved successfully.“)


# Function to handle button click and save data
def save_data(entries):
    projects = []
    hours = []
    for entry in entries:
        project = entry[0].get()
        hour = entry[1].get()
        if project:  # Ensure project name is not empty
            projects.append(project)
        if hour:
            try:
                hour_float = float(hour)
                if hour_float > 0:  # Check if hour is positive numeric
                    hours.append(hour)
                else:
                    print(f”Invalid hours entered for project ‘{project}‘. Please enter a positive numerical value.“)
            except ValueError:
                print(f”Invalid hours entered for project ‘{project}‘. Please enter a valid numerical value.“)
        else:
            print(f”No hours entered for project ‘{project}’. Please enter hours.“)

    if projects and hours:
        save_to_file(projects, hours)
        app.quit()


# Function to update the total hours and progress bar
def update_total_and_progress(entries, total_label, progress_bar):
    total_hours = 0
    for entry in entries:
        hour = entry[1].get()
        if hour and is_numeric(hour) and float(hour) > 0:  # Check if hour is positive numeric
            total_hours += float(hour)
    total_label.configure(text=f”Total Hours: {total_hours}“)

    # Update progress bar
    progress_percentage = min(total_hours / 8, 1.0)  # Ensure the progress is capped at 100%
    progress_bar.set(progress_percentage)

    # Change progress bar color if total hours exceed 8 hours
    if total_hours > 8:
        progress_bar.configure(progress_color=“red”)
    else:
        progress_bar.configure(progress_color=(“lightgreen”, “green”))  # Set back to default green color


# Helper function to check if a string is numeric
def is_numeric(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


# Function to display the content from the last saved text file
def display_previous_entry():
    # Find all text files in the directory
    text_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_directory, “*.txt”))
    if text_files:
        # Get the path of the last modified text file
        latest_file = max(text_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        # Read the content of the file
        with open(latest_file, “r”) as file:
            content = file.read()

            # Create a custom dialog window
            previous_entry_dialog = ctk.CTk()
            previous_entry_dialog.title(“Previous Data Entry”)

            # Display the content in a label
            content_label = ctk.CTkLabel(previous_entry_dialog, text=content)
            content_label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

            # Add a button to close the dialog window
            close_button = ctk.CTkButton(previous_entry_dialog, text=“Close”, command=previous_entry_dialog.destroy)
            close_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

            # Run the custom dialog window
            previous_entry_dialog.mainloop()
    else:
        ctk.messagebox.showinfo(“Previous Data Entry”, “No previous data entry found.“)


# Create and place entry widgets for projects and hours
entries = []

for i in range(10):  # Adjust the range for the number of projects you want to track
    project_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text=f”Project {i + 1}:“)
    project_label.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=“e”)
    project_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(app)
    project_entry.grid(row=i, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    hour_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text=“Hours:“)
    hour_label.grid(row=i, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=“e”)
    hour_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(app)
    hour_entry.grid(row=i, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

    entries.append((project_entry, hour_entry))

# Create and place total hours label
total_label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text=“Total Hours: 0")
total_label.grid(row=len(entries), column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=10)

# Create and place progress bar
progress_bar = ctk.CTkProgressBar(app, orientation=“horizontal”)
progress_bar.grid(row=len(entries), column=5, columnspan=1, padx=5, pady=10)

# Create and place save button
save_button = ctk.CTkButton(app, text=“Save”, command=lambda: save_data(entries))
save_button.grid(row=len(entries) + 1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=10, sticky=“nsew”)

# Create and place “Previous Data Entry” button
previous_entry_button = ctk.CTkButton(app, text=“Previous
```